# Shifting from turbo to Code::Blocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I have been using **turbo c++** but not I have shifted to Code::Blocks and facing following problems

1. clrscr() function of conio.h is not working.
2. Using void main() but it's still asking for return type.
3. getch() showing some error.

What should I do?

```
 #include<iostream>
 #include<conio.h>

 Using namespace std;

 void main(){
     clrscr ();
     int x=10;
     cout<<"hi"<<x;
     getch();
 }
```

Comment: `void main` has *never* been correct. use `int main` (return 0 unless error occured). "getch() showing some error." And what error is that?

Comment: `Using` isn't correct either - it's `using` (lowercase u) - and you shouldn't be doing `using namespace std;` anyway

Comment: Why do your think you need `<conio.h>` and `clrscr`? Reading an up-to-date C++ book sounds like a good idea here, you appear to have learned 90s pre-standard C++.

Comment: Code::Blocks is an IDE, not a compiler - I'm going to assume you switched to a different compiler (Windows versions of Code::Blocks ship with MinGW) which doesn't include *conio.h*, which isn't a standard library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return type of main is int not void. You may also want to put return 0 at the end of main but that's not necessary. The other 2 functions aren't supported in code blocks so look for alternatives

Answer (score 0):

Turbo C has broken C support since its first release, it added a lot of things that are not standard, like conio.h

Code::Blocks should also not be used because its development has stalled a while ago.

Please, use a modern C++ compiler, and if you need, a modern C++ IDE, below is a list of modern ones that could help you.

- CLion
- QtCreator
- Eclipse CDT
- MSVC Express

for C++, please, look into a modern version of any book (look for C++14, your c++ knowledge is from 1992, and I'm saying this not to put you down, but to put you in perspective.)

Comment: There is no Visual Studio Express anymore, there's only the Community Edition (and unlike the old Express versions it does have all the features of the Professional Edition)

Comment: That's Awesome to know.

Comment: Thanks for your help from now I will start using modern c++ compiler .  I in +2 so use the school book but now I have started using  Robert Lafore OOP in C++ (4th edition) not able to download visual c++ can you help in that also

Comment: No, sorry, I cant help about downloading visual c++. The reason for that is that I don't use windows for the last 15 years or so. Why don't you use qt creator? it's easy, free and fast.